# In what way VBW and trace averaging are different in spectrum analyzer?

Tags: rf

We know both VBW and trace averaging intends to smooth the fluctuations of a spectrum.

But how do they differ from each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without getting into DSP and filter theory:

Video bandwidth works by 'smoothing' based on frequency points at *higher and lower frequencies within the same sweep* - It limits how 'sharp' peaks can be.

Trace averaging works by averaging a frequency point with previous versions of the *same frequency point from different sweeps*. This means it doesn't care about the samples at other frequencies, but you need more than one sweep to be able to do it.